# Play/Pause Media Player in Texture View Surface Texture Listener

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview, textureview

I've implemented a recycler view and each item will play video.  My problem is that I need to pause/play the video when it scrolls on/off the screen.

I've implemented that when the user scrolls the video keeps playing.

I have had an issue trying to keep track of the media player when the view scrolls off screen.

I have come up with a solution and I'm hoping I can get some advice to see if may be any issues with the solution.

So I'm using a texture view to display the media player in the recycler view as videoviews aren't compatible when looking to use a recycler or customise the controller.

So in the surface texture destroyed (signalling that the view has left the screen) I pause the media player and when the surfacetexture is available (signalling the view is on screen) I check if the media player is null (as it will be when the screen first loads) if not I start the media player.  Below is my video player class in where you can see my implementation.

```
public class CustomVideoPlayer implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
    private VideoControllerView mControllerView;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private FrameLayout mView;

    public CustomVideoPlayer(Context ctx, TextureView view, ProgressBar progressDialog, FrameLayout holderView){

        this.mContext = ctx;
        mTextureView = view;
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        mProgress = progressDialog;
        mControllerView = new VideoControllerView(ctx);
        mView = holderView;
        mTextureView.setOnTouchListener(new ControlTouchListener());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFullScreen() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggleFullScreen() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mSurface = surface;
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null) {
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(mSurface));
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
        Log.i(VersysVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(surface)+"available");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        //mSurface = surface;
        if(mMediaPlayer==null){
            Log.i(VersysVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName(), "MEDIA PLAYER IS NULL");
        }else{
            Log.i(CustomVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName(), "MEDIA PLAYER IS NOT NULL");
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
        Log.i(CustomVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(surface)+"destroyed");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }

    public void changePlayState(){
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }else{
            Log.i(CustomVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName(), "MEDIA PLAYER IS NULL");
        }
    }

    public void startVideo(String url){
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null){
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            //mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }else{
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(mSurface));
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.i(CustomVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName(), "ON PREPARED CALLED");
        mControllerView.setMediaPlayer(this);
        mControllerView.setAnchorView(mView);
        mControllerView.show();
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
       // mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
    }

    //Touch listener to display video controls
    class ControlTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                mControllerView.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any comments or opinions are welcomed.

Comment: Did you find solution to play/pause textureview video when scrolling?